# Django admin 403 Forbidden error for user even though he has staff permissions and group permissions

Tags: django, django-admin, django-permissions

In the Django admin when the user is accessing a link '/admin/app/routes', there is a 403 Forbidden error, even though he has group permissions and staff status.

Comment: Have you logged in? Have you specified `LOGIN_URL`?

Comment: Yes I logged in with user logins and specified the above url in login_url.

Comment: This question lacks details.  Any number of things can be wrong.